# Why doesn't my element move along the X axis?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried a lot of ways but they don't seem to apply to my scenario. I want the anchor element to move 20px along the x axis.
HTML:

```
<!-- When this is clicked moveElement() is initiated to translateX by 20px -->
<a href="#" id="aButton" class="getStarted" onclick="moveElement()">Get started</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function moveElement() {
      let btn = document.getElementById("aButton");
      btn.style.translateX = "20px";
      // I also tried transform = 'translateX("20px")' but it did not work.
}
```

Comment: The property is called `transform` not `translateX`. Also do not quote the value, it's CSS not JS. `btn.style.transform = 'translateX(20px)'`

Answer (score 0):

translateX is not a valid CSS property.
Perhaps you mean:

```
btn.style.transform = "translateX(20px);";
```

Comment: Please flag this question as a typo